# mongo shell --eval does not run

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unix, database

For some reason I can't eval this simple string in mongo, I think it's because the `$exists` parameter.

```
mongo database --eval "db.products.find({'csv': {'$exists': false}}, {'original.name': true, 'original.sku': true})"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotes are the wrong way around. Use `'` on the wrapping of the statement rather than `"`. Just the important parts:

```
--eval 'db.products.find({ "csv": { "$exists": false } })'
```

Comment: Is curious that wihtout '$exists' original format works fine.